# What relative temperature to expect when saying "increase/decrease temperature" without specifying the temperature

Tags: google-smart-home

With the `TemperatureSetting` trait.
When saying "increase temperature" or "decrease temperature" without specifying any number. We found that the default temperature adjustment seems to be 1.5 °C for our case.

This lead to the question **Why it's 1.5°C? And does everyone experience the same behavior?**

We tried reading the [document](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/temperaturesetting) but it dosen't contain information about this.

We also created [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328687156) to request a feature for this.

Comment: According to info

The 1.5 °C adjustment you're seeing likely  depends on the specific thermostat you're using and its implementation of the trait. Here's a breakdown of why this might be happening:

Manufacturer Default:  It's possible that the thermostat manufacturer  sets a default adjustment value of 1.5 °C  within their implementation of the trait. This would  explain why you're seeing this consistent behavior.

Custom Increment: Some thermostats might allow customization of the default temperature adjustment.  Check your thermostat's manual to see if you can increment it by voice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking a look at the TemperatureRelative (https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/temperaturesetting#action.devices.commands.temperaturerelative) attribute of the TemperatureSetting trait. This allows you to adjust the target temperature relative to the current state.

Based on what value the manufacturer puts here Google will decide by much to increase/decrease the temperature.